# How to margin/pad chartCursor below horizontal axis values

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I'm trying to add a bit of margin to my cursor labels (date) as they slightly transparent and don't look good overlapping. So its a hard one to explain so I have included an image to show you:

[image]

So I'm trying to push that label with the box [Mar 11, 2014, Tuesday] down, by about `30px`.

Looking at the documentation there no official margin or padding for [charCursor](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ChartCursor), but is somewhere else? Or even a temporary hacky solution?

Here what I have currently for chartCursor:

```
"chartCursor": {
    "enabled": true,
    "animationDuration": 0,
    "balloonPointerOrientation": "vertical",
    "bulletsEnabled": true,
    "categoryBalloonDateFormat": "MMM DD, YYYY \n\r EEEE",
    "cursorAlpha": 0.15,
    "cursorColor": "rgba(255,255,255,0.5)",
    "fullWidth": false,
    "graphBulletSize": 5,
    "leaveCursor": false,
    "tabIndex": 1,
    "valueBalloonsEnabled": true,
    "valueLineAlpha": 1,
    "valueLineBalloonEnabled": false,
}
```

I also need to know how to fill the first 4 days (im my example) with a solid block and label but that might be a separated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no property within the AmCharts API that allows you to position the chart cursor's category balloon, but you can use CSS to shift the category balloon's SVG path and balloon text div by styling the `.amcharts-balloon-bg-categoryAxis` and `.amcharts-balloon-div-categoryAxis` CSS classes. For example:

```
.amcharts-balloon-bg-categoryAxis {
  transform: translateY(5vh);
}
.amcharts-balloon-div-categoryAxis {
  transform: translateY(5vh);
}
```

You'll need to set [`addClassNames`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmChart#addClassNames) to true in your chart config in order to make these classes available.

[Demo](http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/6e7cbf8b055639cdee6fca2938f129a3)